# ag-grid renders extra blank column right to the last column

Tags: angularjs, render, ag-grid

I use `ag-grid` with Angular 1.5 and I have defined 5 columns in the following format in an array:

```
[
{headerName: 'Username', width: 150, field: 'username'},
{headerName: 'Full Name', width: 150, field: 'full_name'},
{headerName: 'Location', width: 150, field: 'location'},
{headerName: 'Email', width: 150, field: 'email'},
{headerName: 'Check In Comment', width: 370, field: 'comment'},
];
```

The rendering shows 6 columns with the right-most one being blank. I've tried everything, but I cannot still remove the blank column. See the [image: below screenshot]:

**gridOptions:**

```
options = {
                rowData: dataArray,
                rowModelType: 'pagination',
                columnDefs: getColumnDefs(),
                enableColResize: true,
                enableSorting: false,
                enableFilter: true,
                rowHeight: 25,
                angularCompileRows: true,
                suppressRowClickSelection: true
            };
```

**The html code:**

```
<div style="width: 100%;"
                     ag-grid="vm.gridOptions"
                     class="ag-fresh ag-basic">
                </div>
```

I wonder how to remove the blank column right to the 'Check In Comment' column. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit()` ?

[Source (7min 50sec)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZGHoo3RPGI&t=7m50s)

Comment: how could the problem be solved for fix-width columns?

Answer (score 1):

extra column is there even if we use that api `gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit()`.

[image]